# Bootstrap validation checkmark position

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to move the green validation checkmark further to the left (i.e., increase padding to the right), as it is very tight to the select icon.  Is it possible to do that?

I tried the below:

```
.is-valid {
    padding-right:30px !important;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap uses background image property you just need to change its `background-position`

**For Example**

```
.form-control.is-valid, .was-validated .form-control:valid {
    background-position: center right calc(.375em + .4875rem); /* set position */
}
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you for the help